# can't open Netbeans 8.0.1 with java 1.8.0_20 after upgrade from Mavericks to Yosemite

Tags: java, netbeans, osx-yosemite

Please someone help me, i can't open Netbeans 8.0.1 with java 1.8.0_20 after upgrade from Mavericks to Yosemite . double click on the dock and everywhere is nothing happen.

And also i try open it with terminal open -a "NetBeans 8.0.1.app"; there is error :

LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.0.1.app with error -10810.

Thank you for your attention.

Cheers,

MR

Comment: Try removing both and reinstalling...I've had not trouble running on my MacPro laptop or mini...

Comment: Yeah, seriously considering a clean install of Yosemite...